# What happens to a process in an EC2 instance when I get a 'Broken Pipe' error on ssh?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, broken-pipe

I am using some EC2 instances to run some large jobs I can not run locally. The issue I am seeing is that after a while (X hours since the process started) my connection on my shell gives me a broken pipe error

```
ubuntu@ip-10-122-xxx-xxx:~/stratto/ode$ Write failed: Broken pipe
```

The instance is still there because I can reconnect with no problems, but how can I reconnect and get back at seeing the logs of the process as before the 'Broken Pipe'

Any tip much appreciated,
Thanks!

Comment: Redirect your output to a file (or use tee) and then run the program "nohup ..." to ensure the disconnect doesn't kill it.  BTW, I didn't put this as an answer as this isn't really a programming question :)

Comment: Thanks for both suggestions, I was not aware of tee or nohup so I will learn about them and implement them. Do you think the question is not suited for SO? Can I move it?

Comment: I think it probably isn't quite SO material but I'm fairly new here as well.  I don't know how or where to move it.

Comment: Yes I can't do much either. Lets see what others feel. Thanks anyway for your help. I think you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redirect your output to a file and then run the program "nohup ..." to ensure the disconnect doesn't kill it.  Use "tail -f" to monitor the redirected file.

Note:  Originally said to use "tee" but that won't work.  I think a straight redirect and then tail on the file works.

Comment: Thanks! thanks also for the correction I was starting my test with tee

Answer (score 1):

You can use [screen](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-linux-screen/) to run processes in the cloud even when you are not connected to the server.

```
sudo apt install screen
```

To specifically address the issue described in the original post (e.g. connecting to AWS EC2 instances) I a [basic example](https://gist.github.com/samsammurphy/b145be267214c361c7775c1fc44ffa9c) and a more [advanced example](https://gist.github.com/samsammurphy/4810b4117ebdafabd2cfd11421e97a79) of using screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `"screen"`. Detach from it and ping to google.com. So there ssh session will be active through out the installation.