# EC2 ssh broken pipe terminates running process

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, amazon-ec2, broken-pipe

I'am using a EC2 instance to run a large job that I estimate to take approx 24 hours to complete. I get the same issue described here [ssh broken pipe ec2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943613/what-happens-to-a-process-in-an-ec2-instance-when-i-get-a-broken-pipe-error-on)

I followed the suggestion/solutions in the above post and in my ssh session shell I launched my python program by the following command:

```
nohup python myapplication.py > myprogram.out 2>myprogram.err
```

Once I did this the connection remained intact longer than if I didn't use the `nohup` but it eventually fails with `broken pipe error` and I'm back to square one. The process '`python myapplication.py`' is terminated as a result.

Any ideas on what is happening and what I can do to prevent this from occuring?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should try `screen`.

### Install

Ubuntu:

```
apt-get install screen
```

CentOS:

```
yum install screen
```

### Usage

Start a new screen session by

```
$> screen
```

List all screen sessions you had created

```
$>screen -ls
There is a screen on:
        23340.pts-0.2yourserver    (Detached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-root.
```

Next, restore your screen

```
$> screen -R 23340
$> screen -R <screen-id>
```

Comment: Even with `screen` I get broken pipe.

Comment: I also got the broken pipe. But when I re-log in to the ubuntu server, I can still see the screen running. Command : screen -ls. When I entered the screen screen -R XXXX, where XXXX is the screen number, I can see the codes still running. It worked.

Answer (score 5):

A simple solution is to send the process to the background by appending an ampersand `&` to your command:

```
nohup python myapplication.py > myprogram.out 2>myprogram.err &
```

The process will continue to run even if you close your SSH session. You can always check progress by grabbing the tail of your output files:

```
tail -n 20 myprogram.out
tail -n 20 myprogram.err
```

Answer (score 2):

I actually ended up fixing this accidentally with a router configuration, allowing all ICMP packets. I allowed all ICMP packets to diagnose a strange issue with some websites loading slowly randomly, and I noticed none of my SSH terminals died anymore.

I'm using a Ubiquiti EdgeRouter 4, so I followed this guide here https://community.ubnt.com/t5/EdgeRouter/EdgeRouter-GUI-Tutorial-Allow-ICMP-ping/td-p/1495130

Of course you'll have to follow your own router's unique instructions to allow ICMP through the firewall.